# Select simultenious action on multiple touch on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitouch

I need to implement action event in parallel on multiple touch  and this action event going to execute
 as following:

1)first  touch event is already detected and it going to perform  action method based on the

2) than if i touch with second finger ,
first finger touch action should not end and also start another action event in parallel with  the first action event

note:

==>
here with first touch action event i am getting pixel color 
   and i want to zoom that view by tapping with second action event

thank you for reading my query
help is appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of those:

1. Create a subclass of `UIView`
2. Declare the necessary iVars and initialize them in init method.
3. Implement `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` and use conditional statements.